# How to handle dynamic webtable in robot framework with out using python

Tags: robotframework

I have tried using the code mentioned in the answer for this question :-

i have to select all the check boxes in table data,kindly let me know if i can do it in a better way.

the following is the html:

```
<div class="col-sm-12">
    <table id="grddesignation" class="table display table-bordered dataTable no-footer dtr-inline" role="grid" aria-describedby="grddesignation_info" style="width: 0px;">
    <thead>
        <tr style="text-align: center;" role="row">
        <th style="text-align: center; width: 0px;" class="hidden sorting_asc" tabindex="0" aria-controls="grddesignation" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="EmpId: activate to sort column descending" aria-sort="ascending">EmpId</th><th style="text-align: center; width: 0px;" class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="grddesignation" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Employee Id: activate to sort column ascending">Employee Id</th>
        <th style="text-align: center; width: 0px;" class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="grddesignation" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Employee Name: activate to sort column ascending">Employee Name</th>
        <th style="text-align: center; width: 0px;" class="sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Sunday">Sunday</th>
        <th style="text-align: center; width: 0px;" class="sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Monday">Monday</th><th style="text-align: center; width: 0px;" class="sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Tuesday">Tuesday</th>
        <th style="text-align: center; width: 0px;" class="sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Wednesday">Wednesday</th><th style="text-align: center; width: 0px;" class="sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Thursday">Thursday</th><th style="text-align: center; width: 0px;" class="sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Friday">Friday</th>
        <th style="text-align: center; width: 0px;" class="sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Saturday">Saturday</th></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr role="row" class="odd">
            <td class="hidden sorting_1" tabindex="0">
                <input id="wEmployeeID" class="form-control EmpCode hidden" name="EmpCode" value="962">962
            </td>
            <td>000971</td><td>TESTING TWO</td>
            <td>
                <input id="wsun" class="form-control wsun" type="checkbox" value="0">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input id="wmon" class="form-control wmon" type="checkbox" value="1">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input id="wtue" class="form-control wtue" type="checkbox" value="2">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input id="wwed" class="form-control wwed" type="checkbox" value="3">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input id="wthu" class="form-control wthu" type="checkbox" value="4">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input id="wfri" class="form-control wfri" type="checkbox" value="5">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input id="wsat" class="form-control wsat" type="checkbox" value="6">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: robotframework is nothing but the python, What do you mean by `with out using python`? what is the use case?

Comment: I dont want to use any python class, is it mandatory to learn python if I want to implement robot Framework?

Comment: why did you removed question linked to the post? check the first statement now where is the code? does it make sense? unless you are not clear what are you doing and what you asking no buddy can help you even though they want to help !!

Comment: please read [mcve] and post questions next time accordingly

Comment: Ya I removed it because I was not sure whether it is the right solution of the question I have asked.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have some basic knowledge of python to get started with robot framework

About handling dynamic table - I assume the header field `Employee Id` will have unique value and I plot the xpath using it - following lines should do the work for you with small alteration you can change it as per your requirement -

```
*****  Test Case *****  
Launch browser and select checkbox 
  open browser    file:///C:/Users/xxxx/xxxx/temp.html    Chrome    

#wait until page loads the element  
  Wait Until Page Contains Element    //th[text()='Employee Id']/ancestor::thead/following-sibling::tbody//td[text()='000971']
  
#select the checkbox of sunday for employee id 000971
  select checkbox    //th[text()='Employee Id']/ancestor::thead/following-sibling::tbody//td[text()='000971']/following-sibling::td[2]/input
```

output -

[image]